# Textarea Character Limit Per Line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I want to limit my TextArea's rows with 132 chars. However I also want to see a horizontal scroll bar. I looked into lots of posts and most of them recommends `wrap="hard"` property. But in my case that does not create a scroll bar.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: `textarea { overflow-y: scroll; }`

Comment: @elias94xx `overflow-y` is vertical

Comment: problem is my textarea is smaller than width of a line with 132 chars. So if i use this i cannot wrap. And if i use wrap hard i cannot see scroll lol

Comment: @ergunysr there's nothing so annoying than a textarea with horizontal scrollbars :) can you show us a code example?

Comment: @roXon Sorry, meant `overflow-x` of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set `wrap=off` and then using css set `overflow-x` to `scroll`. Have a look at this working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eKBRt/)

Comment: if you want to wrap it then what do you need the `scrollbar` for ?

Comment: because my textarea's width is smaller than a text with 132 chars. I need to see all line. Designers fault... And i have to send this textarea value to DataBase as an array with 132 character strings. I know it sucks

Comment: then you probably need to wrap your ```textarea``` in a smaller ```div``` with horizontal scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `overflow-y:scroll` style and `wrap=auto` attribute like this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/eKBRt/1/

Comment: still same..and i need horizontal scrollbar